# Saving lat and lang in database using geocoding

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I have a csv file with around 40.000 addresses which I need the lat and lng points from to pinpoint the position of the marker. I know there is a 2500 request limit per day using googles geocoder. but I was wondering if it was possible to geocode these addresses and save the lat and lng points inside my database and repeat this every day untill I have the coördinates of all addresses and if possible, how would I do that?

All help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: There is no problem to achieve this. Just dont hammer the google server. What database is it and how are you connected to it?

Comment: Well. You can write a script to execute this for 2500 records daily. Save the last record index in a local file or database. Next day start from there. You can use a cron job to automate the daily process. However I think you can do this in short segments let's say 60 records execution hourly.

Comment: Please read the terms of use for the google maps geocoding service.

Answer (score 0):

You can technically do it using javascript code as suggested in the commments. Their are even other methods and techniques you can do this with but please be aware of the Google Policies.

Quoting from the official [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions)

***No mass downloading. You will not use the Service in a manner that gives you or a third party access to mass downloads or bulk feeds of any Content. For example, you are not permitted to offer a batch geocoding service that uses Content contained in the Maps API(s).***